# Unable to place error below element

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I want to place error below select element 'term' using errorLabelContainer but it is not working well,  don't know what I am doing wrong

[image]

Name Field

```
<div class="form-group"> 
    <label class="control-label" style="margin-bottom: 5px;">Calendar Name </label>
    <input type ="text" name="calendar_name" class="form-control" data-validate="required" data-message-required="Value Required" />
</div>
```

Term Field

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label" style="margin-bottom: 5px;">Term</label>
    <select name="term" id="term" class="form-control selectboxit" data-validate="required" data-message-required="Please select a term" >
        <option value=""><?php echo get_phrase('select_term');?></option>
        <option value="1"><?php echo get_phrase('1st_term');?></option>
        <option value="2"><?php echo get_phrase('2nd_term');?></option>
        <option value="3"><?php echo get_phrase('3rd_term');?></option>
    </select>
    <label id = "myerror"> </label>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
<script type ="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
     $.validator.setDefaults({ ignore: ':hidden:not(.selectboxit)'   });

 $('#term').validate({ 
        rules: {
            'term': {
                required: true
            }
        },
        messages: {
            'term': {
                required: 'Please select a term'
            }
        },
        errorLabelContainer:'#myerror',

    });

});
</script>
```

Comment: Yes I am using bootstrap, and selectboxit to replace default select

Comment: That question is about 'how to validate select'. I am using selectboxit, and the validation is working , I just want the error to be placed below and not at the top of the select box. As displayed in the image

Comment: I see. Can you post your CSS?

Comment: I am using bootstrap. css. It will be too much,  if I paste it here, perhaps i will have to find an alternative to the errorLabelContainer

Comment: can you post the HTML for one of the working fields?

Comment: I have edited the question

Comment: so what happens if you don't specify `errorLabelContainer`?

Comment: If I don't specify errorLabelContainer, error still display at top,  though I read this could be done with error placement function but don't know how